# What's the proper format for an apache benchmark postfile?

Tags: apache, benchmarking

What's the proper format for an apache benchmark postfile?

Answer (score 18):

nevermind I found the answer:

-p POST file
                 A file containing data  that  the  program  will
                 send  to  the  Apache  server  in  any HTTP POST
                 requests. The contents of the file  should  look
                 like  **name=value&something=other**,  with  special
                 characters URL encoded.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html